# Running a function in different thread in QT

Tags: qt, inheritance, qthread

In Qt Application code `Class A` has one member method like `method1()`. I want to call this method in another member function `method2()` and run `mehtod1()` in a different thread. But what I found from the qt documentation is follows.

1. Inherit a new `class MyThread`(suppose) from `QThread`.
2. Override the function method `run()` with your required code.
3. Create an object of `MyThread` in `Class A` and then call the run function wherever you want.

But the above seems bit complex. Is there any mechanism in Qt so that I can create a new `QThread`(without inheriting) instantly in my `method1()` and run the `method2()` with this thread and then return to `method1()` after execution finishes?

Please let me know if I am not clear in my question.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is a way like you want.

This article will help you to understand why it's not the correct way to inherit from QThread: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

This article will help you to know how use QThread in a real simple way: https://www.qt.io/blog/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache

Comment: so wait, basically in the first link you provided, the author tells me NOT to subclass from QThread, and in the second link another author tells me how easy Qt threads are if i subclass QThread. I'm a bit confused now, but thanks for the links anyway ;) +1

Comment: Not exactly. First article explains why QThread should not be inherited in this case and the second explain how to use the QThread class without subclassing it

Comment: sorry, i noticed that. guess it was too early for me. thanks for clearification ;)

Comment: the links are damage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use QObject slots and signals or event support, combined with threads.

Basically, a QObject's slots called through signal/slot mechanism are executed in the thread that created the QObject. You can also move the object ownership from one thread to another using QObject::moveToThread.

You can also use QCoreApplication::postEvent to post events for execution in the thread the object was created in.

See more about threads and QObjects in Qt documentation ("Threads and QObjects" topic in index).

Going to your problem, you can use two separate objects in different threads to "spread" the execution.